admob-plus in Android Studio: make banner invisible on certain pages
I have successfully got a cordova project running with admob-plus plugin in Android Studio. The banners work perfectly on various pages. Google Play has rejected the app because banners are visible on the embedded YouTube pages. I would like to change this and make them invisible on these pages.  My question: How can I make a banner invisible on pages with YouTube videos? The banners appear automatically and are above the iframe. My attempts with additional iFrames and z-index always show the admob banner. Even links to external html pages with YouTube videos always show the banner that is superimposed on top. How can I make the banner invisible directly on the pages?
In the header of the html pages I have linked to cordova.js and admob.js and then added these snippets with the corresponding AdUnitID:
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/admob-plus-cordova/www/admob.js"></script>
    <script>
        let banner

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
        banner = new admob.BannerAd({
          adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy',
        })

        banner.on('impression', async (evt) => {
          await banner.hide()
        })

        await banner.show()
      }, false)
    </script>

On the html page with embedded Youtube iframe I used the snippet, which does not hide the banner:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/admob-plus-cordova/www/admob.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
   // Obtain user consent first

   await admob.hide() // or start loading ads

   // Load ads here
 }, true)

Is it not possible to do this directly on the corresponding html page via javascript where the banner is displayed and should be invisible? The app is hybrid and based on cordova compiled html-css-javascript files. So there aren't multiple individual layout.xml and activity.java files in the project to put native show/hide banner code in them. I have to use the html-files, right?
